# How to deal with dynamically changing test data set in predictive model

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, panel-data, ensemble-learning, time-varying-covariate

I am working on early student intervention model where I need to predict at risk student. However, the values of the variables in the test data change so as the prediction for that record.

For example a student's performance in a subject improves after a month, as measured by a test score, which earlier was not good. Similarly, some other attributes of some other students change, so my prediction result should also change accordingly.

- How to deal with dynamically changing test data like this?
- Is there any way to automate getting the results from a test dataset from a predictive model?

Comment: Depends on whether you want a prediction at (a) certain moment(s), or a model which is able to update the prediction over time. The simplest way would be to summarize past scores (taking maximum, mean, weighted mean, difference between most recent monthts, etc.). Remember that when you summarize your model becomes usable only after the latest month has passed (if you decide to summarize six month with the mean, the prediction can only be made *after* six months). A more intricate way is a structural equation model (combining estimating the trend in testscores, followed by estimating outcome).

Comment: Thank you @IWS. I want my prediction to change according to the changes in the data set on the fly . I mean , if a record of a student changes , there must be a change in the prediction result accordingly .